# Azure WVD deployment domainjoin failed

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, windows-virtual-desktop, wvd

I am deploying some WVD host-pool session-host VMs.

While doing that, only few of the machines are joining the domain successfully, the others are failing (timeout while waiting for JsonADDomainExtension) and thus the entire deployment fails.

After the failure, logging in to the joindomain-failed machines shows they had successfully joined the domain, and JsonADDomainExtension log shows it finished running after about one minute.

Because some machine joins successfully I can rule out network issues and credential issues.
The user's MachineAccountQuota is set to 15000 - so that is not the problem as well.

The time is set to the right time, also - it seems like the machine is actually joined successfully and the problem is Azure reading that state.
It looks like when I'm reseting the password using azure Password Reset blade machines that were stuck on joindomain phase will finish with this state and become ready

Comment: The extension relies on powershell DSC (Desired State Configuration) - which is configured to reattempt to run the script until the DSC is achieved (which is probably why you see they are domain joined at a later time). This suggests that when the script first tried to run, it failed for some reason - check eventvwr around the time when the extension failed (+/- 5 minutes).

Comment: I don't see anything odd in the event viewer. Looks like it succeeded on first try. I can see in the event viewer the time has changed during deployment, maybe it has to do with that?

Comment: Time is an important factor in the domain join process - if the time is off by more than a couple of minutes, the token that the client uses will not be accepted by the server.